# Mysql 5.5.45 crashing after refreshing web page rapidly(Too Many Connection warning)

Tags: mysql, wordpress, amazon-ec2, database-connection

I am using ec2 aws instance for my wordpress webiste.after every 5 to 10 minute and randomly my website going down i tried lots of things like increasing buffer memory ,memory limit but that not working for me so any one know how do i resolve this issue bellow snpiet is the error log

Mysqld log :- http://pastebin.com/8Gp0V5g3

error log:- http://pastebin.com/cpEHHUwm

```
160201 14:44:06 [Warning] /usr/libexec/mysql55/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 104  user: 'wordpress2'

160201 14:44:06 [Warning] /usr/libexec/mysql55/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 73  user: 'wordpress2'

160201 14:44:06  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
160201 14:44:07  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 2756685
160201 14:44:07 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysql55/mysqld: Shutdown complete

160201 14:44:07 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
160201 14:44:08 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
160201 14:44:08 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysql55/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.46) starting as process 14406 ...
160201 14:44:08 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
160201 14:44:08 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160201 14:44:08 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
160201 14:44:08 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
160201 14:44:08 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
160201 14:44:08 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160201 14:44:08 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160201 14:44:08 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
160201 14:44:08  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
160201 14:44:09 InnoDB: 5.5.46 started; log sequence number 2756685
160201 14:44:09 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
160201 14:44:09 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
160201 14:44:09 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
160201 14:44:09 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
160201 14:44:09 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysql55/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.46'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

show full table wp_options as bellow:-

[image: wp_options]

my.cnf file setting in /etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
# Settings user and group are ignored when systemd is used.
# If you need to run mysqld under a different user or group,
# customize your systemd unit file for mysqld according to the
# instructions in http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd
#max_connections = 1000
#wait_timeout = 120
#interactive_timeout = 120
#max_allowed_packet = 64M
#innodb_buffer_pool_size = 800M
#innodb_buffer_pool_size = 384M
#max_user_connections = 500
[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

error after refreshing the page rapidly.
[image: after refreshing]

Comment: What size ec2 instance are you using?

Comment: @BruceP  i am using m4.xlarge ec2 instance